# Error Converting Hex to Float

Tags: java, android, floating-point, hex

I am trying to convert this Hex Value **C2DE70A4** in Android. This is the Code that I am writing for Conversion:

```
try {
        String hexString = "C2DE70A4";
        float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16));
    }

catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But it is causing an Exception and telling me that **Invalid int: "C2DE70A4"**

Can anyone help me to make the Conversion? The Float value should be: **-111.22**

Thanks.

Comment: float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat((int)Long.parseLong(hexString, 16));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0xC2DE70A4 in decimal is 3,269,357,732, but an int's max value is 2,147,483,647. That's why you can't parse it -- the parsed value is too big to fit in an int.

You should parse the string as a long, then cast it to an int , and finally call `Float.intBitsToFloat` on that:

```
long asLong = Long.parseLong(hexString, 16);
int asInt = (int) asLong;
float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(asInt);
// or, just
float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat((int)Long.parseLong(hexString, 16));
```

**Detailed explanation:**

Fundamentally, the problem is that C2DE70A4 represents an unsigned value, whereas ints in Java are signed. If you parse it as a long and then look at its bits (via `Long.toBinaryString`), you'll see:

```
11000010110111100111000010100100
```

That's a 32-length string, because `toBinaryString` omits leading 0s. So why didn't it fit in a 32-bit int? Because that binary string above represents an *unsigned* number. Or, more precisely, it's really shorthand for this *signed*, 64-bit, [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) number:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000011000010110111100111000010100100
```

... which equals 3269357732 in decimal, which is out of the range of an `int` because an `int` is signed, meaning that the leftmost digit is the sign and not part of the number's magnitude (aka how "big" it is).

If you take that `long` and cast it to an `int`, it'll discard the leftmost 32 digits, leaving you with a 32-bit int `11000010110111100111000010100100` -- which corresponds to -1025609564 in decimal (again, in two's complement). If you then take that number and feed it to `intBitsToFloat`, you'll get -111.22.

Answer (score 2):

change the hex string to 0xC2DE70A4..

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String myString = "BF800000";
    Long i = Long.parseLong(myString, 16);
    Float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(i.intValue());
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(f)));
}
}
```

Comment: I think this answer would be much improved if you explained _why_ that code fixes it, rather than just providing code without comment. Teach a person to fish vs giving them a fish, and all that.